# Searching words without spaces for word with spaces in solr

Tags: search, text, solr, space, words

Lets us suppose I have title field(text type) with its value as "ice cubes".So it will be indexed into two tokens as "ice" and "cubes". Now if I search for "icecubes", no results are found since "icecubes" neither matches token "ice" or "cubes".

The vice-versa of this is also possible.So how should I handle this situation. Is there any feature with solr to manage this ?

Comment: Need more input - What exactly is "vice versa" here? What does your solr schema look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` with an option `catenateAll="1"`.
This will causes all subword parts to be catenated. Example:

```
"wi-fi-4000" => "wifi4000"
```

and this will fix your problem.

About the viceversa you can use `generateWordParts="1"` (together with `splitOnCaseChange="1"` and maybe `splitOnNumerics="1"`) option on the same filter.
This causes parts of words to be generated. Example:

```
"PowerShot" => "Power" "Shot" (if splitOnCaseChange=1)
"Power-Shot" => "Power" "Shot"
```

but you need the words to be at least camelcase or Solr has no way to understand where to split the word.

remember also to set `preserveOriginal="1"` if you want your original work to be also tokenized as it is.

Comment: Lets suppose I have the following 4 values in the title field.
1=>"ice cubes", 2=>"icecubes",3=>"Reusable colorful ice cubes", 4=>"colorful icecubes". If I search for "icecubes", I am getting 1,2,4  results but not 3. why so ?. When i can fetch 2 resulst then why not 3 as well.

Comment: for such a specific question you need to send your field definition. there is no way to know if I donøt know how your tokens are created. Maybe you could accept this answer and open this more specific question including your field definition...

Comment: For a field value "colorful ice cubes", this is generating "colorful","ice","cubes","colorfulicecubes" as indexed text. Is to possible to generate "colorfulice","icecubes" as indexed text.

Comment: Here the link to the configuration of the title field http://pastebin.com/NbifVeWp

Comment: try adding solr.ShingleFilterFactory before the other filter and let me know if it gets better. unfortunately is difficult to foresee all cases but this should fix most of them.

Comment: Do you want me to add solr.ShingleFilterFactory along with existing worddelimiter configuration ?

Comment: how can i search "ice cube" if I have "icecube" in my index. I have set mm as  2<-1 4<70%. While using shingle in query analyzer, the query "ice cube" creates three tokens as "ice","cube", "icecube". But mm is the limitation here. How to solve it ?

Comment: mm 2<-1 4<70% means if there are less than 3 optional clauses, they all must match; for 3 to 4 clauses, one less than the number of clauses must match, for 5 or more clauses, 70% must match, rounded down. Your case is the first, so all the clause must match giving you therefore a match on that doc. I don'e see the problem here.

Comment: Maybe you should close this question and open a new one describing with a longer example what is this other problem.

Comment: link to new question in detail : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502261/searching-words-with-spaces-for-word-without-spaces-in-solr

Comment: I accept the first answer dated 14 aug. But your next answer given 2 days back for the next question is not working. But I accept the shingle answer given by you. How about my new question ?

Comment: I really appreciate the answer. I really worded for me. But I am not able to solve the second case. 
"ice cube"(search) not matching "icecube" (index). Though the vice-versa case using shingle as suggested by you worked for me :)