# Searching words with spaces for word without spaces in solr

Tags: search, solr, token, space

how can i search "ice cube" if I have "icecube" in my index. I have set mm as 2<-1 4<70%. While using shingle in query analyzer, the query "ice cube" creates three tokens as "ice","cube", "icecube". But mm is the limitation here. Only ice and cubes are searched but not "icecubes".i.e not working for pair though I am using shingle filter. However in analysis tool, three tokens are created. How to solve it ?.
Here the schema configuration link: http://pastebin.com/74xaKEyv

Comment: mm 2<-1 4<70% means if there are less than 3 optional clauses, they all must match; for 3 to 4 clauses, one less than the number of clauses must match, for 5 or more clauses, 70% must match, rounded down. Your case is the first, so all the clause must match giving you therefore a match on that doc. Can you send your query how it gets parsed in debug mode?

Comment: (+((DisjunctionMaxQuery((titlex:mac)~0.01) DisjunctionMaxQuery((titlex:hine)~0.01))~2) DisjunctionMaxQuery((titlex:"(mac machin) hine"~3^3.0 | mcatname:mac hine^0.5 | smalldesc:"mac hine"~3^1.5 | companyname:"mac hine"~3^0.9 | catname:mac hine^0.5)~0.01))/no_coord
Here the debug query with mm= blank(no mm specified) and yet not working

Comment: see that '(mac machin) hine'? I suspect it should become '(mac machine) hine' to work... it may be the stemmer... can you try with another example?

Comment: (+DisjunctionMaxQuery((titlex:"(ice icecub) cube"~50)~0.01) DisjunctionMaxQuery((titlex:"(ice icecub) cube"~3^3.0 | mcatname:ice cubes^0.5 | smalldesc:"ice cube"~3^1.5 | companyname:"ice cubes"~3^0.9 | catname:ice cubes^0.5)~0.01))/no_coord
debug query for search string "ice cubes" where "cubes" are getting stemmed to "cub"

Comment: and you don't have "cub" in your index... I wonder why...

Comment: can you analize the tokens create d and send the exact sequence of what tokens are created?

Comment: Here the two snapshot showing how tokens are created in Solr Analysis tool.Pic 1: http://picpaste.com/Screenshot1-fi32TtFE.png & pic 2
http://picpaste.com/Screenshot2-24071GPZ.png. In the anaysis tool, "icecubes" are getting highlighted against "ice cubes". However when I make solr query, such results are not shown.

Comment: mmm you seems to have all the right tokens in your index, every single token in your query is in the field in the index, so it can only be something to do with the way the query gets built.

Comment: Can you try to query only ONE field and see what happens? Then remove WordDelimiterFilterFactory from the query analizer and see what happens, that will help us understand what part of the query is not being hit.

Comment: its still not working . this is the debug query for "stic ker" against "sticker". 
<lst name="debug">
<null name="rawquerystring"/>
<null name="querystring"/>
<str name="parsedquery">
(+MultiPhraseQuery(title:"(stic sticker) ker"))/no_coord
</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">+title:"(stic sticker) ker"</str>
<lst name="explain"/>
<str name="QParser">DisMaxQParser</str>
<str name="altquerystring">
org.apache.lucene.search.MultiPhraseQuery:title:"(stic sticker) ker"
</str>

Comment: Why do you always change test data? If you want to fix your problem you have to work with the same set of data until you get it work.

Comment: I apologize for this. Lets take "ice cube" as example now onwards.
<lst name="debug"><str name="rawquerystring">"ice cubes"</str><str name="querystring">"ice cubes"</str><str name="parsedquery">
(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((titlex:"(ice icecub) cube"~50^2.0 | smalldesc:"ice cube"~50)~0.01) DisjunctionMaxQuery((titlex:"(ice icecub) cube"~3^3.0 | mcatname:ice cubes^0.5 | smalldesc:"ice cube"~3^1.5 | companyname:"ice cubes"~3^0.9 | catname:ice cubes^0.5)~0.01))/no_coord
</str>

Comment: Is the last query with or without the WordDelimiterFilterFactory on the query? Does it work if you run a query only on one field? like this: 'DisjunctionMaxQuery(titlex:"(ice icecub) cube")'

Comment: This is with WordDelimiterFilterFactory. But I have tried searching without WordDelimiterFilterFactory on the query but it was not working. Yes, I have tried searching on single field also. But still it did not worked.

Comment: anu updates Maurizio sir ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Shingle filter only at indexation in your schema.

Try removing `<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true" tokenSeparator=""/>` from the query part of your analyzer.

Comment: If I remove shingle filter from query analyzer, then the query "ice cube" will not be finding results for "icecubes", which is desirable. Since you asked me to remove the shingle filter from query time, I did it but it is still not working.